Should I tell recruiter I have gotten another job offer after agreeing to fixed term work?
A recruiting agency got me a 3 month contract with a reputable company. They said there's a good chance for extension/renewal. The pay rate is a bit low. Also the start date was pushed back by about a week which makes me skeptical. Recently I received a job offer for a permanent position that pays more. For various reasons I think I would be more comfortable with the first job, from the recruiting agency. Should I tell the recruiting agency I received another job offer? Can I use the job offer to negotiate a pay raise, either now or in the future? They have already said that if the contract gets renewed there would be a pay raise, should I ask now how much it would be?

I can't prove it but I strongly suspect the recruiter is taking a large cut of my pay.

Tell us more about the timing: did your start date get pushed back a week to start tomorrow (or sometime soon) or pushed back a week starting 3 months from now? As the old saying goes: a bird in the hand is worth 2 in the bush.

The recruiter always takes a chunk of the pay, that's how they make money.  Typically it's around 33% in the US.  While you won't see that deducted from your check, that will be taken from the budget the company internally gives to the role.  For external recruiters for a full time position, it's generally 3-4 months of the full year pay of the role (note:  that's what the recruitment company makes, not the individual recruiter).

My answers to your three questions are: no, no, and sure.  While I don't have much experience with the contracting world, I can't imagine that trying to leverage another job offer for a pay raise during a trial contract will result in anything positive for you. Since you already accepted it, IMO trying to negotiate a raise now - especially when there is a promised raise in 3 months - is bad faith and would likely burn bridges. Since you can't use the offer, there's also no reason to communicate it to the agency. On the other hand, if the full-time gig would be more attractive to you with a higher salary, you could tell them you have another offer you intend to accept and can't say yes to them unless they can raise their offer. No real downsides to trying. As for asking about the raise value, I see no reason why not to ask. It is reasonable for you to want to know what you would potentially be making to be able to plan your finances for the future.Also I just noticed your comment... that's not how recruiters work. If you mean the company is willing to pay you less because the recruiter gets a cut from them, then maybe but also if they use recruiters they're aware of the drawbacks. It is on you for not having a higher standard of pay and for accepting something you're apparently unhappy with. The recruiter isn't "taking" anything from you.

Couple of responses for you:

Should I tell the recruiting agency I received another job offer?

The agency has negotiated a minimum and maximum hourly rate with the end client, even before contacting you.  You've already agreed to a rate.  Stomping your feet for more money now is grounds for you to be cut and replaced.  If you exhibit this behavior now, it's assumed you'll do it again.

Can I use the job offer to negotiate a pay raise, either now or in the future?

Nope.  I'm boggled as to how you think this would be relevant in the future.

They have already said that if the contract gets renewed there would be a pay raise, should I ask now how much it would be?

If you don't have this in writing, DON'T BELIEVE IT.

I can't prove it but I strongly suspect the recruiter is taking a large cut of my pay.

Do you think they should do it for free?  It's not "your" pay.  Agencies have to pay for the skilled professionals who find this kind of work.  It's not easy.  Turnover is very high, as well as competition.  In the U.S. they have to pay their staff, office overhead, and their lawful portion of Medicare/Social Security taxes above what you get paid.  25% markups are not unusual.

Be strong.
You are not a partner for the recruiters, you are a resource for them. Their partners are the employers.
The recruiter gets about 3 monthly salary of you, either if you get the job or at you pass the trial period. They lie to you that it is not your problem, because your employer pays it. In the reality, this is why your employer will likely give you a much smaller offer, or prefer a direct applicant!
Any "safety" what the recruiter says, is in illusion. What do you think, would they employ you if you do not have a job? No, of course no.
